# viewController does not have a member named fbuser

Tags: ios, swift

There is an error:

> viewController does not have a member named fbuser

How can I solve this error?

```
let fbrequest = FBRequestConnection.self
FBRequestConnection.startWithGraphPath("me?fields=feed", completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
    if (error == nil) {
        let fbGraphObject = result as FBGraphObject
        let feed = fbGraphObject.objectForKey("feed") as NSMutableDictionary
        let data = feed.objectForKey("data") as NSMutableArray
        let postDescription = data[0].objectForKey("description") as String
        //println( post )
        self.fbuser.initialUserFeed = feed
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SelectStreams", sender: self)
    }
    else {
        //TODO Allert to user that something went wrong                 
        println(error)
    }
})
```

Please explain what this error is and how I can fix it.

Comment: The error means that the line `self.fbuser.initialUserFeed = feed` can't work because `fbuser` doesn't exist in `self`. Either you forgot to declare it before using it, or it is out of scope.

Comment: I don't see where `self.fbuser` is declared. It may be related.